# Let E have measure zero. Show that if $f$ is a bounded function on E, then $f$ is measurable and $\int_E f= 0.$

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question regarding problem 9 in section 4.2 of Royden's Real Analysis. When solving this problem, my instructor said It suffices to consider $f$ non-negative since we can consider the positive and negative parts of $f$ separately.

What does he mean by that? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

$f=f^{+}-f^{-}$ where $f^{+}=\max \{f,0\}$ and $f^{-}=-\min \{f,0\}$. $f^{+}$ and $f^{-}$ are also bounded. So if we prove the result when $f$ is non-negative we get $\int_E f=\int_E f^{+}- \int_E f^{-}=0-0=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The professor means to break E up into E$^+=\{e\in E \mid f(e)\ge 0\}$ and E$^-=\{e \in E \mid f(e) \le 0\}$. Now just consider $\displaystyle\int_{E^+}f$. If you can prove the statement true for E$^+$, it is certainly true fior E$^-$.